# Gradient Paint not showing up JAVA

Tags: java, swing, gradient

Hello Im trying to make a gradient line to show up on a black background and either the background is black or the gradient line shows up. Both won't happen at the same time. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1440, 900));
        frame.setVisible(true);
}

 @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        GradientPaint redToBlack = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.RED,
                0, 1300, Color.BLACK);
        g2.setPaint(redToBlack);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 0, 5, 1000));


    }
```

Comment: Or implement an `Icon` and use `frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new YourIconClass()));` if you don’t want to subclass a component class.

Comment: The "content pane" covers the frame so you will not see your custom painting. Instead, you can extend JPanel and override the paintComponent(....) method and then add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.